# ReactJS dropdown menu (using Semantic UI) won't fire onChange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I've been struggling for the past few hours trying to get a simple dropdown change event to work, using ReactJS and Semantic UI. From my understanding, the onChange property of the  element is supposed to fire the event handler it is bound to when a different option is selected. Here is my code:

```
var DictionarySelector = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return  {value: ""}
    },
    handleChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
        console.log('Dropdown changed');
        return;
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="ui form" style={{marginTop:'55px'}}>
                <div className="field">
                    <select className="ui dropdown" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="">Select Dictionary</option>
                        <option value="1">Dictionary 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Dictionary 2</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
             </div>
         );
     }
 });
```

Everything seems ok, and I did a bunch of research about this, but nothing happens when the option is changed in the dropdown. The handleChange function is never called. Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of it, but you're missing open braces on your style attribute: `style="marginTop:'55px'}}>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soooo after a ton of experimenting and different attempts i figured out that everything was set up perfectly, but I had been initializing the Semantic UI dropdown with a JQuery command elsewhere which was causing some issues.

Comment: I have similar problem like you, where did you put code initializing semantic dropdown? Because i try inside componentDidMount and directly inside application.js (i work with rails) but this doesn't  work.

Comment: How did you do that @jkatz94?

Comment: I think what I ended up doing was using a standard dropdown (not initialized with semantic UI) and then having the standard onchange event fire. Semantic and react don't play well with one another unless you use some library like react-semantic-ui

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/11301/) that is working.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var DictionarySelector = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return  {value: ""}
    },
    handleChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
        console.log('Dropdown changed');
        return;
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="ui form" style={{marginTop:'55px'}}>
                <div className="field">
                    <select className="ui dropdown" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}>
                        <option value="">Select Dictionary</option>
                        <option value="1">Dictionary 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Dictionary 2</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
             </div>
         );
     }
 }); 
React.render(<DictionarySelector />, document.getElementById('container'));
```